# Add get_focus() and has_focus is change to True

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

```
window = self.builder.get_object("main-window")
print window.get_focus()
print window.has_focus()
print window.is_active()
print window.has_toplevel_focus()
```

Terminal output:

```
<MainWindow object at 0x28c26e0 (Mainwindow at 0x26a1210)>
False
False
False
```

So I got the right answer on get_focus(), but when I ask, MainWindows has the focus it is return with False. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`get_focus()` returns the widget that *would have focus* if your top level window got focus.

Comment: So how can I fin a solution for my problem: I would like to write a method when MainWindow's focus is change.

Comment: No need for @ergosys, I get notification on any comment on my answer. Best is to add a seperate question (that's how this site works), but as a hint, you can get signaled on any property change.  Look at the properties for Window.